# Where to place the Value Object code that is shared by more than one Aggregate Root?

Tags: domain-driven-design, node.js, aggregate, typescript, value-object

I have 2 Aggregate Root:
One is the `Lessor` user, and the other is the `Lessee` user.

```js
class Lessor extends AggregateRoot {}

class Lessee extends AggregateRoot {}
```

Each of these Aggregate Roots has a `email` property, it is a Value Object.

```js
class Email extends ValueObject { }
```

```js
class Lessor extends AggregateRoot {
    private email: Email
}

class Lessee extends AggregateRoot {
    private email: Email
}
```

I am not sharing an instance of `Email`, I am sharing the code of `Email`.

#### Can I put the `Email` code in the `SharedKernel` folder?

- I didn't want to duplicate the `Email` code by placing it in the`Domain` folders of each Aggregate Root.
- And don't even put the `Email` code in one of the Aggregate Roots and import it in the other.

Comment: You don't need to duplicate *code*; place it wherever you want - if you have some place that you use to put shared domain code, place it there; DDD doesn't mandate anything organizational at that level of detail. Also, I get the impression that you've read somewhere that DDD mandates folder names and a certain folder structure - it does not. There is a concept of a "shared kernel" in DDD, but it isn't really a folder; rather it's a strategy for coordinating between *different teams* working on different bounded context.

Comment: So, if that's what your `SharedKernel` folder is meant to be, then don't place it there, but maybe make some other shared folder. If you don't really have to coordinate with another team, then maybe rename that folder and place your code there. But ultimately, you (and your team) are free to organize your own code as you see fit.

Comment: Wonderful! I understood!